# Why does String.startsWith takes Pattern as input when String.endsWith takes String

Tags: dart

There is this interface mismatch between two methods that do something very similar.

```
bool endsWith(String other)
bool startsWith(Pattern pattern, [int index=0])
```

What is the reason for that? What were the thoughts of the authors?

Comment: That's a good question...
If you have an optional index with startsWith, you could shove that pattern anywhere, not just the start. In that manner, endsWith could just be a convenience function.
It looks like they should rename startsWith to patternMatch().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API of `Pattern` doesn't provide any means to search backwards for a match. If `endsWith` took a pattern it would need to try one by one to find matches from the back of the string (which would most likely be in O(n^2)).

Note, that you can't just use `Pattern.allMatches` and see if the last match ends at the end of the input:

```
var re = new RegExp('a|ab');
re.allMatches('ab'); // => one match: 'a'.
```

In this example only 'a' is matched and if we used the `allMatches` iterator to determine if the string ends with the given regular expression it would wrongly fail.

Comment: I assumed that it's normal for a regexp engine to be able to search backwards by stepping through state machine in opposite direction but it turns out the only regexp engine capable of doing this is the one in .NET

Also, it is pretty unfortunate that you cannot simple extend the pattern and anchor the end of it with $

Comment: We took the same Regular Expressions as JS. They are fast and not too bad. Wrt to .Net: you would still need to create a new FSM, but it should be doable.  Even then you would need to change the Pattern interface. Currently it's relatively simple but with `searchBack` it would be harder to implement.